# How to fix NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 404

Tags: java, android, json, networking, android-volley

i am using gofile link but when i call it i get  this error

```
 E/Volley: [4463] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 404 for https://api.gofile.io/getFolder?folderId=XuxRGg
```

i also attach the code part

```
public class GoFile {
    public interface goFileCallback {
        void onSuccess(String result);
        void onError(VolleyError error);
    }

    public static void getStreamLink(Context context, String url, final goFileCallback callback) {
        String[] parts = url.split("/");
        String id = parts[4];
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, "https://api.gofile.io/getFolder?folderId="+id, response -> {
            JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(response, JsonObject.class);
            JsonObject data = jsonObject.get("data").getAsJsonObject();
            JsonObject contents = data.get("contents").getAsJsonObject();
            for (String keyStr : contents.keySet()) {
                JsonObject md5 = contents.get(keyStr).getAsJsonObject();
                String link = md5.get("link").getAsString();
                callback.onSuccess(link);
            }
        }, error -> callback.onError(error));
        queue.add(sr);
    }
}
```

i would be glad if some one help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You should double check the link "https://api.gofile.io/getFolder?folderId=XuxRGg".  Typing it in chrome also return 404.

Comment: actually when i type it it shows Cannot GET /getFolder. i have bought it from codecanyon i tried my best in analysing entire code but still this i cant understand how developer getting the folder id from url  actually in gofile api it shown as 'https://api.gofile.io/getServer'

Comment: as per this website  API https://gofile.io/api

Answer (score 0):

say 404_Not Found response code -
check api link and find    http_response_code(404)(in php) - probably there isn't response in database

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).